# Keras/Tensorflow prediction used in another program to calculate loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

There is a pipeline I want to try that utilizes Keras/Tensorflow with another program. My 'very professional' diagram below shows what I am trying to accomplish

[CNN with external program pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a49HT.png)

The input to the CNN is a 2D-matrix and the output is a 2D matrix with the same dimensions as the input matrix. I want to feed the prediction into a separate program, which computes a new 2D matrix that should then be compared with the input matrix to calculate the loss.

*I know that this would be slow to compute*, but I still want to know if it is feasible. My first idea was to modify the loss function to interface with the external program - but a small amount of research seems to indicate that this is not possible. Is there some other way to interject a separate program to the loss function, or is there some other way to rework this pipeline?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that no, in general this is not possible. This is due to the fact that CNNs and any Neural Network is trained by using backpropogation along with a loss function. If you want to perform backprop you need to know the process that turned input x into output y. This way you can compute the gradient. If you use a blackbox program as part of the equation it becomes impossible to backprop.

A few possible suggestions.

- If it is feasible you could train a conv net to emulate the blackbox program and then it will be possible to use it as part of training.
- You could do some other form of optimization that works without gradients/works with blackbox loss functions.

Comment: I do not fully understand how this would affect the backpropagation. The external program produces predictable results - it would almost be like multiplying the predictions by random numbers. Using backpropagation to optimize the input to the external program would optimize the output of the external program.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. First of all, multiplying the predictions by random numbers is not a learnable task. But beyond that, if you wanted to optmize the input to the external function then train your model without the external function, you will need to know what 'optimal' is for your training data up to when you feed it in. Finally, if you want to use the output of the external program to optimize your initial function then yes, that would affect backprop.

Comment: Yeah, multiplying by random numbers is a bad example. I know what is optimal for my training data since the output from the 'black box' program should be identical to the input to the CNN. Say instead that the prediction is multiplied by 5 and compared to the input. If the input is 5, shouldn't then the network be able to optimize itself to output 1 without knowing that the prediction is multiplied by 5?

Comment: Yes and no. First this sounds like you are trying to make some sort of autoencoder, I don't understand why you have a blackbox program if it is completely determined then just code what it does up and then use that to train your model. The crux of this argument is that you need to be able to take a gradient. If it just multiplies by 5 then taking the gradient is very easy and you could just write that up. Otherwise, no because I could get from 1 to 5 in any number of ways 5 = 1*5, 5 = 1+4, 5 = 1*2 + 3, etc. How does the program know how to take the gradient of a blackbox then?